# Some continuous function in an interval, provided with values at some points only.

Tags: functions

A function $f(x)$ is continuous in the interval $[0,2]$. It is known that $f(0)=f(2)=−1$ and $f(1)=1$. Which one of the following statements must be true?

(A) There exists a $y$ in the interval $(0,1)$ such that $f(y)=f(y+1)$

(B) For every $y$ in the interval $(0,1),f(y) = f(2−y)$

(C) The maximum value of the function in the interval $(0,2)$ is $1$

(D) There exists a $y$ in the interval $(0,1)$ such that $f(y) = −f(2−y)$

---

Here's my approach:

Consider a function $g(y) = f(y) - f(y+1)$ since $f$ is a continuous function and $g$ is a combination of $f$ so it is also continuous in $[0,1]$.

it is found that

$g(0)=f(0)-f(1)=-1-1=-2$ and

$g(1)=f(1)-f(2)=1-(-1)=+2$

since $g$ goes from $-2$ to $+2$ and is continuous in $(0,1)$ therefore there has to be a point in b/w $(0,1)$ such that $g(\text{that point}) = 0$

when $g(y)=0$ for some $y\in(0,1)$ then $f(y) = f(y+1)$, Hence **statement A** is true.

Using the same logic **statement D** is true too. It is clear that statement B and C can be false.

The answer booklet says that only **statement A** is true. There is no comment on **statement D**; should it be considered false? Is my approach okay?

Comment: Can you tell me where you found this beast from ?

Comment: If you haven't made some mistake copying the problem, (D) must indeed be true. Your approach is good, only instead of "statement B and C are false", it would IMO be better to say that they _can_ be false. After all, there are functions satisfying the given conditions for which they are true.

Comment: thanks for the verification and pointing the _can_ out. I made the edit.

Comment: @avDec25 statement D is necessarily true i have cross verified with one of my (not so genius) friend and he agrees with you , he emphasised ......exists **a 'y'** in the inte.....

Comment: @avDec25 also try posting an appropriate Answer so that it would help someone who tackles the same problem

Comment: @daniel Fisher : the statement says MUST be true.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon Yes. And they need not be true. Yet, for a given $f$ they may be true, so I consider it better to say that staments (B) and (C) _can be false_ or _need not be true_ than to say that they _are false_. It would be different if the statements quantified over $f$, but they only relate to one (unspecified) $f$.

Comment: You are right. Anyways, the correct answer to the question should only be "A,D".